# Injecting test module with dagger2

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, dagger-2

I use Dagger2 in my android app. 
Basically I inject a `HttpClient` (interface)  in `MainActivity`.

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule{

   @Provides public HttpClient providesHttpComponent(){
        return new RealHttpClient();
    }
}

@Component( modules = MainActivityModule.class )
public interface MainActivityComponent {
   public MainActivity injectActivity(MainActivity);
}



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   public void onCreate(Bundle saved){
      super.onCreate();

      injectDependencies();
   }


   protected void injectDependencies(){

      Dagger_MainActivityComponent
        .builder()
        .mainActivityComponent( new MainActivityModule())
        .build()
        .injectActivity(this);
   }

}
```

So far so good, that works like expected. Now I want to write some unit tests  (not android instrumentation tests) for `MainActivity` where I want to use `TestMainActivityModule` instead of `MainActivityModule`.

```
@Module (overrides = true )
public class TestMainActivtiyModule extends MainActivityModule {

   @Provides public HttpClient(){
      return new MockHttpClient();
   }

}
```

My question is: How do I force `MainActivity` to use `TestMainActivitiyModule` instead of `MainActivityModule`? Is there a good solution for that?

My current approach is to use inheritance and to override `getModule()`, something like this

```
public class TestMainActivity extend MainActivity {

   @Override
   protected void injectDependencies(){

      Dagger_MainActivityComponent
        .builder()
        .mainActivityComponent( new TestMainActivtiyModule())
        .build()
        .injectActivity(this);
   }
}
```

and to run unit test against `TestMainActivity` instead of `MainActivity`.

I guess it works, but one of the problems I'm facing with this approach is that I can't start `TestMainActivity` with an `Intent` because I can't specify it in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Does anyone know a better approach for unit testing with dagger2 on android?

Comment: As an initial comment, module overrides is not a thing in dagger 2.  The method is there so as to not break compilations while people are migrating, but is deprecated and has no effect on a dagger 2 project.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I've started using has involved maintaining two modules (one for the app, one for testing) in parallel build variants (ex: `app` and `integration`).  Still not sure how well that solution scales so YMMV.  I'd be very happy to see a better solution!

This is also a great read: http://engineering.circle.com/instrumentation-testing-with-dagger-mockito-and-espresso/

Comment: I prefer having two separeted modules, so the circle.com blog post is not what I want (since I don't want to have mocking dependencies in my release app). The build variants approach sounds better, but still not perfect ...

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest you to check this [boilerplate](https://github.com/xresco/Android-Agile-Boiler-Plate) since it is fully based on DI using Dagger2. It also shows how you can replace your dependencies in the test environment in a very neat way.

The dependencies currently handled by the boiler plate are the following:

- Database dependency: encapsulates all the database operations.
- Shared preferences dependency: deals with shared preferences.
- Local files dependency: which deals with saving on files.
- Analytics dependency: covers all the operation of reporting events to your analytics backend (GA, Segment, FB, Flurry ..)
- Logging dependency: encapsulates all the operations related to logging to your console
- Api dependency: encapsulates all the API related operations

The power of dependency injection comes really handy especially for testing since you can easily switch your dependencies in the test environment to dummy dependencies.